# Decrease repeat measurements in Benchmark android

Tags: android, performance, benchmarking, android-jetpack

By default,

```
benchmarkRule.measureRepeated {
```

runs the test for 50 times with warmups.
Is there any way we can reduce the run to 10 or something?

Found out we can configure instrumentation arguments with

```
testInstrumentationRunnerArgument 'androidx.benchmark.startupMode.enable' , 'true'
```

that captures 10 measurements.

but this doesn't want "measureRepeated" to be used,
we get:

> java.lang.AssertionError: Error - multiple benchmarks in startup mode.
> Only one benchmark may be run per 'am instrument' call, to ensure
> result isolation.

Any idea on how this can be taken ahead?

Comment: why you think that test runs 50 times?

Comment: You can have a look at reference link at the most bottom, it runs for 50 repititions.
https://proandroiddev.com/going-deep-on-androidx-benchmark-d06b89765f9e

Even in my output Json file that is generated from the library, i can see there are 50 timestamps generated to aggregate the final result.

Answer (score 0):

I find they way how you can decrease count :

```
    @Before
    fun init() {
        val field = androidx.benchmark.BenchmarkState::class.java.getDeclaredField("REPEAT_COUNT")
        field.isAccessible = true
        field.set(benchmarkRule, 1)
    }
```

Where 1 is the number of repeat count.

but you need to be careful - this can greatly affect the stable work for library